# How to find the distinct equivalence classes for the set of all bit strings of length 5

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations, bit-strings

> Let B denote the set of all bit strings of length 5,
>   $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5$. Define a relation R on B by: two bit strings
>   are related by R if and only if they both have bits $b_1$ the same and both have
>   the bits $b_5$ the same.
>
> (a) List all the elements of the equivalence class [10010].
>
> (b) How many distinct equivalence classes are there? List them.

So we never went over bit strings in class and I'm trying to apply the same concepts as a similar question that had integers and ordered pairs.

For part (a), the elements of the equivalence class [10010] is just 0 and 1?

For part (b), the distinct equivalence classes are all of the variations of the 5 bit strings where bits $b_1$ and $b_5$ are the same? for example, [10010] and [11110]? How would I go about determining the exact number of distinct equivalent classes?

Any help is appreciated,

thanks in advance

Comment: Well, can you give a single string equivalent to $10010$ other than itself?

Comment: I don't understand your answer "$0$ and $1$"...neither of those are strings of length $5$.

Comment: Every  string with $b_1 = 1$ and $b_5 = 0$ is in the equivalence class of 10010

Comment: I guess I'm confused by what the question means by the word element. An element of the equivalence class.

Comment: Ah, thanks. so every string with [1 _ _ _ 0] and filling in the blanks with variations of 0 or 1 is an element of [10010].

Comment: And for part (b), the distinct equivalence classes would be [1 _ _ _ 1] [0 _ _ _1] [0 _ _ _ 0] [1 _ _ _ 0] plus all the variations of 1s and 0s in the blanks?

Comment: Jamie Yes! Great job.  I'd encourage you to post your solution as an answer to your question.

Comment: (And also accept your solution, too!)

Comment: Thanks @amWhy and @lulu! I've posted my solution. One thing I'm unsure of, would [10010] be considered an element of itself? i.e [10010] is an element of the equivalence class [10010]?

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

(a) [10010] [10110] [10100] [10000] [11000] [11100] [11010] [11110]

(b) 4 distinct equivalence classes. 
 [10000] [10001] [00000] [00001]

Comment: No.  (b) asks for how many *distinct equivalence classes.*  Not for each element of each class.

Comment: @Wildcard So the distinct equivalence classes would be [10000] [10001]  [00000] [00001] ?

Comment: Yes, and the actual answer is "4."  And then execute the further instructions given by writing what you just commented.  To do math textbooks you should get good at exact readings and executions of what is stated.  *"How many distinct equivalence classes are there? List them."*

Comment: @Wildcard Thanks for the help and tips!